# Should clicking on a label trigger the label's associated form control's onclick handler?

Tags: html, onclick

If I say

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="foo" onclick="alert('foo!')">foo</label>
```

and click on the word foo, is the onclick supposed to trigger?  Where in the html5 specification would I find this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**
Found it!

> For example, on platforms where clicking a checkbox label checks the checkbox, clicking the label in the following snippet could trigger the user agent to run synthetic click activation steps on the input element, as if the element itself had been triggered by the user:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element

Comment: I've just found the html5 reference

Comment: thanks, that was it (though you linked to an old draft of the spec); I had read that but didn't bother to follow the "run synthetic click activation steps" link.